# Parametrizing any arbitrary Conic

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, parametrization, homogeneous-equation

Given the implicit equation of a Conic $C$, how to determine its parametric representation?
I went thought [this report](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-20-winter/Handouts/a228715.pdf) and it has an algorithm:

> 1. Fix a point $p$ on the conic. Consider the pencil of lines through $p$. Formulate the line equations.
> 2. Substitute for $y$ in the conic equation, solve for $x(t)$.
> 3. Use the fine equations to determine $y(t)$.

The algorithm described requires determining a point on the conic. Is there an algorithm to determine a rational point on a conic?

Comment: You could solve the equation of the conic for $x$ and then try to find those values of $y$ (if they exist) giving a perfect square as discriminant.

Comment: @Aretino I am not sure how this will work. Suppose my equation is x^2 + y^2 = 4. Solving for x, I get x = sqrt(4 - y^2) or x = -sqrt(4 - y^2). How do I proceed further? I want to implement this algorithm in a computer program so I am avoiding iterating over points.

Comment: You should have some algorithm to find a value of $y$ (in this case $y=0$) making the quantity under square root a perfect square. But why do you need a rational point?

Comment: Thanks but this will not be trivial for other conics. @Aretino I need a rational point to form the equation of line cutting the conic at the point. This will parametrize the conic.

Comment: But why RATIONAL? Wouldn't a real value be fine?

Comment: Yes, I think it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110583/discussion-between-fracker011-and-aretino).